# Create three columns of equal size (resizable)

Tags: html, css, width

I want to create a modular interface with three columns, all three of which should basically have the same width, with a divider between each.

If you then hold down the divider and drag to the left or right, the **surrounding two columns** should increase/decrease in width respectively, but not the last element, that should remain unchanged.

What approach should I try?
Thanks in advance!

Here are some visualizations of my plans:
[image: Standard view]

When you drag & drop the divider between the purple and blue field:
[image: Dragged view]

I've tried it so far with `flex: 1;` and then always changing the flex-basis, but this **affects the width of all three elements**, not just the two surrounding ones.

If I'm using `width` for resizing, the mechanics of adjusting columns widths works, but the default view doesn't work because I don't know how to evenly distribute the width across all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting with each column having flex: 1, giving your container a total of flex 3 space. Remember this for later.

**Flex values**

- purple —— flex: 1
- blue   —— flex: 1
- green  —— flex: 1

Going further, if each columns starts with equal widths, then each starts with 0.3333333333 width out of 1. Let's focus on the widths without flex.

**Width percentages:**

- purple —— 0.3333333333
- blue   —— 0.3333333333
- green  —— 0.3333333333

If you want to change box widths two at a time, try changing each of the 3 box's flex values individually (e.g., using `document.querySelector()` and setting `purpleBox.style.flex = '0.1'`). That way, the proportions will remain correct even if you resize the whole container. The main thing you have to understand is that each box's width is a function of the percentage position of the dividers relative the whole container. So if the first divider is 25% from the left of the container, then the purple box must 25% (0.25) of the width. If the second divider is 80% from the left, then the green box must be 20% (0.2) of the width (i.e., 1 - 0.8). Finally, the blue box must be 55% (or 0.55) of the width (i.e., 0.8 - 0.25).

**New width percentages**

- purple —— 0.25
- blue   —— 0.55
- green  —— 0.20

Finally, if we tie the flex values back into it, we know that the *total* container has flex 3, so the final flex values (in order of purple, blue, green) would be their percentage widths multiplied by 3.

**New flex values**

- purple —— 3(0.25) = flex: 0.75
- blue   —— 3(0.55) = flex: 1.95
- green  —— 3(0.20) = flex: 0.60

(notice how 0.75 + 1.95 + 0.60 adds up to the total 3 flex of the container?)

Hopefully that helps you get started. Essentially, whenever you drag a divider, you need to run that computation (purple = left divider percent, blue = right divider percent minus left divider percent, green = 1 minus right divider percent) and then set each box's flex value accordingly.